# update related information in oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am using oracle 10g and I have information present like below:

Here we have codes and set. All codes will be part of some set.
Requirment is to all the codes below to set must have the same information as set ( same postal and street as of the set).

| code | Bill | Deliver | set | postal | street |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABC001 | ABC002 | ABC003 | ABC001 | 110082 | RK Puram |
| ABC002 | ABC002 | ABC002 | ABC001 | 110087 | Nagloi |
| ABC003 | ABC003 | ABC003 | ABC001 | 110091 | Sarojni |
| XYZ001 | XYZ002 | XYZ002 | XYZ001 | 511008 | Hinjewali |
| XYZ002 | XYZ002 | XYZ002 | XYZ001 | 511002 | Wakanda |

so it should look like this

| code | Bill | Deliver | set | postal | street |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABC001 | ABC002 | ABC003 | ABC001 | 110082 | RK Puram |
| ABC002 | ABC002 | ABC002 | ABC001 | 110082 | RK Puram |
| ABC003 | ABC003 | ABC003 | ABC001 | 110082 | RK Puram |
| XYZ001 | XYZ002 | XYZ002 | XYZ001 | 511008 | Hinjewali |
| XYZ002 | XYZ002 | XYZ002 | XYZ001 | 511008 | Hinjewali |

I have written below plsql to perform, it seem to working fine but since I have 50 such column similar to postal and street. I was wondering if this can be done via SQL or better plsql.

```
for i in (select code, bill, Deliver , set  from table)
      loop
      
        select code , postal, street into lcode, lpostal, lstreet from table where code=i.set;
      
        if ( i.set <> i.ship) then
          update table set postal=lpostal,  street=lstreet  where code=i.ship;
        end if;
    
        if ( i.set <> i.bill) then      
               update table set postal=lpostal,  street=lstreet  where code=i.bill;                      
        end if;
    end loop;
```

Comment: What is the logic for knowing which street and postal code to retain?

Comment: street and postal for bill and deliver should be same as of set code.

Comment: Yes, but there are three different postals and streets for set ABC001. What makes you decide for 110082/RK Puram?

Comment: set and code is same ABC001. for code ABC001 it's 110082/RK Puram.

Comment: Okay. Wemust look for the same code. I missed that. However, it seems you are fighting an inappropriate data model here. If the set shall have one postal and street, then why is there no set table containing one row per set containing the set's postal and street? It looks like you'd better fix the data model rather than muddling through with that non-normalized date that you must update every time you spot a divergence.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you are fighting an inappropriate data model here. The table is not normalized and so whenever you see divergences, you must get rid of them via updates. If this assumtion is true, then the *real answer* is: fix the data model.

As to updating the data, this looks like a simple update to me, only that you want to update a tuple (postal and street belonging together):

```
update mytable t
set (postal, street) =
(
  select t2.postal, t2.street
  from mytable t2
  where t2.code = t.set and t2.set = t.set
);
```